# Are all vector spaces closed under addition and scalar multiplication? If so, why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The [definition of a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space#Definition) doesn't explicitly include closeness under addition and multiplication.

Is there a proof that shows or disproves it?

Comment: It depends what additional structure you give the vector space. If you read the article you reference as far as the section "Vector spaces with additional structure" you would find plenty of material on this.

Comment: Is $17$ closed? Vector spaces are not meant to be closed, since there is no definition of closed vector space. Maybe you are confusing "closed" with "closed under addition and scalar multiplication".

Comment: If you take the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$, then it is closed. If you take the usual metric on $\mathbb{Q}^n$ it is not closed.

Comment: @almagest Closed in what? Any topological space is closed in itself.

Comment: I meant "closed under addition and scalar multiplication", my bad. I'm editing my question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I was using "closed" loosely in the sense of complete, because I could not see any other interpretation which gave a sensible question. But the OP's recent edit makes clear that that was silly of me - the question is not sensible!

Comment: @almagest I don't think I have ever seen the term "closed" mean "complete".

Comment: The fact that the space is closed under the operations is part of the definition of the term "operation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have told us what your question is about, I want to direct your attention towards the associativity axiom, which says that for *arbitrary* vectors $u,v,w$, $u+(v+w)=(u+v)+w$. This implicitly assumes that the vector space is closed under addition of vectors, because you can't apply the addition on elements not belonging to the vector space. Similarly, the axiom $a(bv)=(ab)v$ assumes closure under scalar multiplication.

This page should ease your worries: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html . Read the very very first line.

Comment: You seem to be talking about closure not closeness! I recommend deleting this answer before it is downvoted.

Comment: I am in the process of editing my answer.

Comment: Oh sorry. My English is very weak, as you can already see.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, but I meant "closed under addition and scalar multiplication", my apologies. I'm new to linear algebra, and I'm still not entirely familiar with its terminology.

Comment: Oh my word. @almagest was talking about me having written about "closure" earlier, and was asking me to delete it. That's astounding, so I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry, badly worded questions are a curse!

Comment: You're right, that explains it. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly right! I was wondering, but the second page put things in it's place.